# How to INDEX MATCH from Muliple colums?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq0KM.png)

I want to get a formula so that if any of those codes are given F column, it should fetch the value of the corresponding value from the yellow area to the G column. Can i use vlookup Here? Or INDEX MATCH ? I am beginner sheets user. Please help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell `G1` (make sure you delete everything below):

```
=arrayformula({"value";iferror(vlookup(F2:F,{split(flatten(B2:D&char(9999)&A2:A),char(9999))},2,0),)})
```

[image]

Comment: GOT IT. Works Like a Charm. Thanks a ton mate. You saved my day and night.